# How to combine Database fields label together in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi 
I am working in .Net crystal reports with asp2.0 and VS2010, now what i want is
i have four fields, drag and dropped, AddressName, AddressCity, AddressZip etc, now i have placed their labels and they repeat, what i want is, one label should have AddressName,AddressCity,AddressZip combined, like  507 Eden Towers Main Boulevard Gulberg, Lahore 54000. And also, i dont want separate fields to be combined as they overlap on lengthy record, i want one label with everything related to address binded.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new formula field, and in that formula concatenate your fields together:

```
{YourTableName.AddressName} + " " + {YourTableName.AddressCity} + ", " + {YourTableName.AddressZip}
```

Then, instead of the AddressName, AddressCity and AddressZip fields, put your new formula field on the report instead.

Comment: Thanks buddy, your reply rocks, gonna rate you!!!  oh yeah one thing more, do you have idea how can i divide section into columns, i mean i have 4 columns to display and they overlap when i place their labels

Comment: @Muhammad - do they overlap horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a text label and drag any report field in the label. That way, the text is actually concatenated and you won't have any spacing problems.